# Defined global variable in javascript becomes undefined again

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head><meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&region=vi&language=vi">    
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var map;
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        html {
            height: 100%;
        }

        body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(10.79, 826.694),
                zoom: 13,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
                mapOptions);
        }
    </script>    

    <script>            
        alert(map);
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

A couple of my functions need to use the `map` variable, however, I keep receiving alerts that complain `map` variable is unidentified.
How can I make browser remember that map was defined on `map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
                    mapOptions);`
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` wil be `undefined` when that `alert()` runs.  This is because the `alert()` will execute before your `initialize()` method.

`<script>` tags in the body will run immediately, but the `onload` function you specify wont run until after all body tag contents (and the scripts within it) have been parsed and executed.

So once `initialize()` is called, this setup will work like you want and the global variable `map` will be avaliable everywhere.

Comment: Yeah, there are some critical pieces of knowledge like that but I did not know. Thank you

Comment: So what is the difference between `<body onload="something">` and `<body> ..many things here...<script>something</script></body>`?

Comment: @MinhTriet If the script tag is really the last things in the body tag, very little.

Comment: @AlexWayne that is incorrect. There is a big difference between onload and at the end of the body! Images may not be loaded at that point in the body. Onload waits for them to be all loaded.

Answer (score 3):

that's because you call the function `initialize()` onLoad, meaning the map-variable is assigned onLoad.
But the script

```
<script>            
    alert(map);
</script>
```

is called before `onLoad` is triggered

try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(10.79, 826.694),
            zoom: 13,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            mapOptions);


        alert(map);
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Because

```
<script>            
    alert(map);
</script>
```

is fired before

```
onload="initialize()"
```

is called.

Comment: Yeah, there are some critical pieces of knowledge like that but I did not know. Thank you